# update an entry in hashMap without using apache.commons functions

Tags: java, hashmap

I want to maintain a state table, where the states have been defined using a enum

```
private enum states {
    contension_initiated, contension_failure, contension_success, reservation_success, reservation_completed, reservation_failure
}
```

and the state table is maintained using

```
HashMap<Integer, states> stateTable = new HashMap<Integer, states>();
```

depending on the conditions the values in the stateTable would vary/change 
how can the same entry in the hashMap be modified without using the apache.commons libraries?

I have been doing this until now :

```
if(condition1)
      stateTable.put(1,state.contension_initiated)
if(condition2) 
      stateTable.remove(1)
      stateTable.put(1,contension_success)
```

Comment: Why would you need to remove the item?

Comment: @MadProgrammer how can i maintain the state/ change the state of the same entry in HashMap from contension_initiated to contension_success associated with the same key ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(condition1)
      stateTable.put(1,state.contension_initiated)
if(condition2) 
      stateTable.put(1,contension_success)
```

HashMap will maintain only a single unique key.  Therefore, if you try and "put" a key that already exists, it will replace the value associated with the key (rather then adding a new key)

Comment: was not aware of this I thought it would throw an exception, my bad for not trying

Comment: Sometimes, these things simply are not obvious.  Glad to be of assistance :D